# HTML Hyperlink turns into normal text on using " position : relative , top , left " properties in CSS

Tags: html, css

When I'm using position : relative , top:45px, left:900px; inside .nav a{}, my hyperlink turns into a normal text but if I omit that part it works as expected that is as a link . Not being able to figure out
how to fix this , I don't to change its position but want to make that hyperlink work as well . I tried using the float:right property as well but still the same thing happens , I'm not being able to click on it .

Expected Result : Even if I use position: relative , top, left properties in CSS , my hyperlink works as a link that is when I click on it , it redirects me to the desired page , but the problem that I'm facing is that when I'm using these properties the hyperlink turns into just text , I can't click on it , they appear as texts not links which would redirect to a certain page .

This is my HTML and CSS code :

```css
.nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav{
    background-color: black;;
    padding: 7px;
}

.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left: 900px;
    top: 45px;
}

#heading h1{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 145px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    color: teal;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

img{
    position:relative;
    width: 60px;
    top: -90px;
    left: 80px;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar li:hover{
    text-shadow: teal;
}

#jumbo{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/21/07/16/learning-3245793_960_720.jpg');
    min-height: 300px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    
}
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/Home.css' %}">
    <title>Science Professor</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="navbar">
        <div class="nav">
            <li><a href="{% url 'topic' %}">Topics</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'publish' %}">Article</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="heading">
        <h1>Science Professor</h1>
    </div>

    <img src="https://www.nfscars.net/media/accounts/2017/01/23/photo.jpg" alt="">

    <section id="jumbo">

    </section>
    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just tell me what result you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "a normal text" and "works as a link" ? Please define clearly what is the problem and what is the expected result

Comment: by normal text i mean , they don't work as links which would redirect me to the desired page on clicking it , they are static and I can't click on it , they are just mere text objects . They are inside a <a> tag , that is a hyperlink tag , but when using those CSS  properties they don't work as links , but I want them to work as one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of using the right `z-index` for the overlapping elements. Although there could be a better way of implementation, I have set the `z-index` on `<a>`tag and on `<h1>` tag in css in a way that `<a>` tag has higher z-index then `h1` tag.

Now the links are clickable.

```css
.nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav{
    background-color: black;;
    padding: 7px;
}

.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left: 900px;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#heading h1{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 145px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    color: teal;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
}

img{
    position:relative;
    width: 60px;
    top: -90px;
    left: 80px;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar li:hover{
    text-shadow: teal;
}

#jumbo{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/21/07/16/learning-3245793_960_720.jpg');
    min-height: 300px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    
}
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/Home.css' %}">
    <title>Science Professor</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="navbar">
        <div class="nav">
            <li><a href="{% url 'topic' %}">Topics</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'publish' %}">Article</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="heading">
        <h1>Science Professor</h1>
    </div>

    <img src="https://www.nfscars.net/media/accounts/2017/01/23/photo.jpg" alt="">

    <section id="jumbo">

    </section>
    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: z-index is a tricky thing. Thanks buddy , it solved my problem .